# Data analysis optimazation

Tags: python, statistics, data-analysis

I have a dataset with cars being spotted on two different cameras. I need to calculate the average time it takes to travel from camera 1 to 2. Database looking like so:

```
"ID","PLATE", "CSPOTID", "INOUT_FLAG","EVENT_TIME"
"33173","xys8","1","0","2020-08-27 08:24:53"
"33174","asd4","1","0","2020-08-27 08:24:58"
"33175","------","2","1","2020-08-27 08:25:03"
"33176","asd4","1","0","2020-08-27 08:25:04"
"33177","ghj1","1","0","2020-08-27 08:25:08"
 ...
```

Currently my code works as intended and calculates the average time between different rows. But working with big data and having a flow of incoming data, it takes too much time.

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pandas as pd,collections, sys, operator, datetime
df = pd.read_csv('tmetrics_base2.csv', quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',', dtype={"ID": int, "PLATE": "string", "CSPOTID": int, "INOUT_FLAG": int,"EVENT_TIME": "string"})
data = df.as_matrix()

#Sort values by PLATE
dfSortedByPlate = df.sort_values(['PLATE', 'EVENT_TIME'])

#List for already tested PLATEs
TestedPlate = []
resultList = []
#Iterate through all rows in db
for i,j in dfSortedByPlate.iterrows():
    # If PLATE IS "------" = skip it
    if j[1] == "-------":
        continue
    if j[1] in TestedPlate:
        continue
    TestedPlate.append(j[1])
    for ii,jj in dfSortedByPlate.iterrows():
        if j[1] != jj[1]:           
            continue
        if j[1] == jj[1]:
            dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(jj[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(j[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            Travel_time = []
            Travel_time.append((dt1 - dt2).total_seconds())
            # Discard if greater than 1 hour and less than 3min
            if (dt1 - dt2).total_seconds() < 3000 and (dt1 - dt2).total_seconds() > 180:
                resultList.append((dt1 - dt2).total_seconds())
                #print((dt1 - dt2).total_seconds())
                print(sum(resultList) / len(resultList))
            placeholdertime = jj[4]
```

I have sorted the database by plate number so that the comparison should be fairly quick. Any advice or pointers to where I could increase run speed would be greatly appreciated.

Also I am unsure of how long time I should expect calculations like these to take? I don't have experience with data in this scale.

Comment: I think you loop way too much. A first step could be that you fetch all the plate values (probably `set(dfSortedByPlate['PLATE'].values())`) and then process the Frame in plate-chunks (pivot the Frame).

Comment: What is the expected output based on the given input?

Comment: Expected output is average travel time based on the the different timestamps recorded. A  lot of the data is throwaway, since cars either deroute from point A to B or take a stop and invalidate the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed up your code by removing unnecessary for loops. You can use in-built pandas functions that are typically faster than iterating through rows in the df. For instance, you can replace the two for loops by:

```
#get only relevant plates
df_relevant = dfSortedByPlate[dfSortedByPlate['PLATE'] != "-------"]

#test relevant plates
for i,j in df_relevant.iterrows():
    df_same_plate_j = df_relevant[df_relevant['PLATE'] == j[1]]
    for ii, jj in df_same_plate_j.iterrows():
        dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(jj[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(j[4],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        Travel_time = []
        Travel_time.append((dt1 - dt2).total_seconds())
        # Discard if greater than 1 hour and less than 3min
        if (dt1 - dt2).total_seconds() < 3000 and (dt1 - dt2).total_seconds() > 180:
            resultList.append((dt1 - dt2).total_seconds())
            #print((dt1 - dt2).total_seconds())
            print(sum(resultList) / len(resultList))
        placeholdertime = jj[4]
```

`df_relevant` now contains all plates that you want to test. Then, `df_same_plate_j` gets the rows in `df_relevant` that have the same plate as row `j`. Then you do the rest. This way, the number of items you are iterating over is much less.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am gonna change the pre filtering process to be outside the loop. The reason for double looping is to check the value of x against y. This was my initial approach to the issue, not sure how I can get rid of a for loop without losing the entire checking process.

Comment: One option is to use indexing. It seems like you need to check each row in the df against each other right?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Need to check for same plate values and compare the timestamps from point A to point B. How would indexing help we work around double for looping through the database?

Comment: Based on this information, I added some new things to my answer. After you get `df_relevant`, you loop through all rows in `df_relevant` and store rows with matching plates in `df_same_plate_j`. Then you only iterate over rows in `df_same_plate_j` in the second loop. It will save many iterations and may speed up code substantially.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. How would I go around fetching the event_time from the df_same_plate_j object. The code above doesn't run because jj[4] can't be accessed in the 2nd loop. Also how does your method differ from the one posted? I also use the 1st loop to skip "------" and plates that have already occured.

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo in the second for loop: replaced `for ii, jj in df_same_plate_j:` to `for ii, jj in df_same_plate_j.iterrows():`. It should work now. The methodology is the same as what you have posted since you do need the for loops, but you can reduce the iterations in the for loops to speed up your code by using in-built pandas functions to get `df_relevant` and `df_same_plate_j`. In your code, the runtime is O(n^2). In the code I am suggesting, the runtime is O(k*m) where k is the size of `df_relevant` and m is the number of rows where the plates match (note: k<n and m<n).

Comment: Thank you for the help and explanation. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few suggestions:

Read only what you need:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_raw.csv',
                 quotechar='"',
                 skipinitialspace=True,
                 delimiter=',',
                 usecols=['PLATE', 'EVENT_TIME'],
                 index_col=['PLATE'])
```

Convert the `EVENT_TIME` column to `datetime` (you don't have to do that row by row):

```
df['EVENT_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EVENT_TIME'])
```

Sort (you already did that):

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.sort_values(by='PLATE', inplace=True)
```

Fetch the plates, excluding the one that isn't needed):

```
plates = set(df.index).difference({"------"})
```

Process the plate-chunks:

```
for plate in plates:
    print(df.loc[plate])
```